# SED pattern matching

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to modify NGINX config file using **sed**. I wand to replace the values of ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key

```
config="/etc/nginx/httpd.conf"
certfile="server.pem"
keyfile="key.pem"

sed -i -e "s/\(ssl_certificate *\/etc\/pki\/nginx\/\).*/\1$certfile/" $config
sed -i -e "s/\(ssl_certificate_key *\/etc\/pki\/nginx\/private\/\).*/\1$keyfile/" $config
```

With the starting lines that I want to modify looking like this

```
ssl_certificate /etc/pki/nginx/selfsigned.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/nginx/private/selfsigned.key;
ssl_dhparam /etc/pki/nginx/dhparam.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```

I end up with

```
ssl_certificate /etc/pki/nginx/server.pem
ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/nginx/server.pem
ssl_dhparam /etc/pki/nginx/server.pem
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```

What I am trying to achieve is to substitute **selfsigned.crt** with **server.pem** and **selfsigned.key** with **key.pem** to achieve

```
ssl_certificate /etc/pki/nginx/server.pem
ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/nginx/key.pem
ssl_dhparam /etc/pki/nginx/dhparam.pem
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```

Please, advise. TIA

Comment: You end up with different values for ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key, so it seems that you have accomplished your goal.

Comment: What is the value of the variable `$ssl_certificate`?  I suspect you need to omit the `$` and use the literal string `ssl_certificate`.

Comment: I just realized I made a typo - it is not $ssl_certificate but ssl_certificate. There are no variable in pattern, just naked text.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed "/certificate/s|\(.*/\).*\(.$\)|\1$certfile\2|" input_file
ssl_certificate /etc/pki/nginx/server.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/nginx/private/server.pem;
ssl_dhparam /etc/pki/nginx/dhparam.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```

Match lines with `certificate` and carry out the substitution on those lines.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
cat /etc/nginx/httpd.conf | sed -e "s/\(ssl_certificate *\/etc\/pki\/nginx\/\).*/\1$certfile/" -e "s/\(ssl_certificate_key *\/etc\/pki\/nginx\/private\/\).*/\1$keyfile/"

server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name _;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;


    ssl_certificate /etc/pki/nginx/server.pem
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/nginx/private/key.pem
    ssl_dhparam /etc/pki/nginx/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```